# Looping within SQL Server - Iteration of IPs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Sample Input

[image: IP Start]

Sample Output

[image]

I believe this could be solved using WHILE Loop but not able to figure out how to unpivot it into a single column and at the same time increment only the last number.

EDIT: IP Ranges are made by me, I picked them randomly.

Comment: You *could* do this with a while loop, but a Tally would be *far* better.

Comment: If these are real IP ranges, you may need to increment more than just the last number. It would possibly be better to store them as integers rather than text; converting them form and to dotted-decimal notation in your presentation layer.  Storing data like this in a human-readable format is just adding extra work for yourself.

Comment: The *real* hard part (tbh) is when you have a range like `121.11.32.0` to `121.12.17.255`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have solved your issue. With this technique we also solve the issue mentioned by [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) in the comment.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (IP_start varchar(15), IP_end varchar(15))
DECLARE @i int=1

INSERT INTO @tbl (IP_start, IP_end)
VALUES ('121.11.32.0','121.11.32.5')
,('121.11.33.11','121.11.33.11')
,('121.11.34.0','121.11.34.4')
/*,('121.11.35.0','121.11.36.15')*/


;WITH cte 
AS
(SELECT 
t.IP_start, t.IP_end
,CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(t.IP_start,4) AS int) AS binary(1))+CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(t.IP_start,3) AS int) AS binary(1))+CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(t.IP_start,2) AS int) AS binary(1))+CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(t.IP_start,1) AS int) AS binary(1)) AS ip_Bin
FROM @tbl t 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
tt.IP_start, tt.IP_end
,cast((cast(cte.ip_Bin AS int)+@i) AS binary(4))
FROM cte INNER JOIN
@tbl tt ON tt.IP_start=cte.IP_start AND cte.IP_end=tt.IP_end
WHERE cte.ip_Bin<CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(tt.IP_end,4) AS int) AS binary(1))+CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(tt.IP_end,3) AS int) AS binary(1))+CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(tt.IP_end,2) AS int) AS binary(1))+CAST(CAST(PARSENAME(tt.IP_end,1) AS int) AS binary(1))
)
SELECT CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(cte.ip_Bin,1,1) AS int) AS varchar(3))+'.'+ CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(cte.ip_Bin,2,1) AS int) AS varchar(3))+'.'+ CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(cte.ip_Bin,3,1) AS int) AS varchar(3))+'.'+ CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(cte.ip_Bin,4,1) AS int) AS varchar(3))
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.IP_start
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I was able to use this successfully. It does not work when you have duplicates but worked, in the end, worked when I cleansed my Data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave this answer in case it helps anyone.  This is for Postgres however.

It is not clear what the base types are, but you can use `inet` functions for this -- by converting to an `int` and back again:

```
select ip + '0.0.0.0'::inet, (ip + '0.0.0.0'::inet)::text, host(ip + '0.0.0.0'::inet)
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(ips::inet - '0.0.0.0'::inet, ipe::inet - '0.0.0.0'::inet, 1) ip;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662805/convert-ip-address-in-postgresql-to-integer) is a db<>fiddle.

The first column is an `inet` representation of the value.  The second is a string representation, but using standard IPV4 notation.  The final looks like the input data.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server has these `inet` functions, but the main idea to store IP addresses as integers is valid.

Comment: This could be correct. I liked the approach. However, I was not able to test this as I use SQL Server.